# fseek and fread on a file containing a list of parts

Tags: c, file, pointers, fread, fseek

I have a file containing a list of parts and part numbers. What I need to do is display the name of the part at a location given by a file pointer and an integer. Something like `sizeof(part) * n` and then display the information for the part at that location.

I am trying fseek and fread but it does not seem to be working properly.

```
FILE * ofp;
ofp = fopen("file.bak", "r");

char p[sizeof(part)];

fseek(ofp,sizeof(part) * 4,SEEK_SET);
fread(p, sizeof(part), 1, ofp);
printf("%s", p);
```

It prints the first part on the list, when it should be printing the 4th.

The part is a structure containing 3 fields. They are of the form:

```
1 item1 2
4 item2 80
```

where the first number is the item number and the second is the number in stock,
so they are not all the same length. They are however converted to a binary file, that is the ofp.

Comment: Is each line of the file a fixed length?  Can you post a sample of the file?  As well as the definition of part?

Comment: Do you mean to be opening `ifp` to read and then reading from `ofp` ??

Comment: ifp was a typo. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: What is the format of the binary file? What is the format of `part`?

Comment: How about instead of `char p[]` you try a `part seek_part;` that's been memset() and then use seek_part instead of p in the fread() since you only need one of them.

Comment: @n0741337 could you please show me an example of how this would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I was thinking for you to try:

```
FILE * ofp;
ofp = fopen("file.bak", "r");
part seek_part;

memset( &seek_part, 0, sizeof(part) );
fseek(ofp,sizeof(part) * 4,SEEK_SET);
fread(&seek_part, sizeof(part), 1, ofp);
printf("%s", seek_part.name);
```

This still won't compile, but you should get the idea.  We'd need to see the part typedef to be able to really show the correct printf().

Comment: would the p in the printf need to be seek_part? when I run it with p it has a p is undefined error and when i run it with seek_part is displays nothing.

Comment: heh - my first effort would have benefitted from compilation :)

Comment: Is there any chance that I could email you the code and associated files to look at?